# How can I force pytest to render newlines in reprs (e.g. for Pandas DataFrames) in test failure output?

Tags: pandas, pytest

I have this test:

```
import pandas as pd
def test_foo():
    df = pd.DataFrame({k: list(range(10)) for k in 'abcdefghij'})
    assert len(df) == 0
```

When I run this with `python3 -m pytest .`, I see this in the failure output:

```
E       assert 10 == 0
E        +  where 10 = len(   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j\n0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1\n2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2... 6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6\n7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7\n8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8\n9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9)
```

The `repr` of the dataframe is hard to read. I want to see the whole dataframe instead of an ellipsized version, and I want to see newlines rendered as actual newlines instead of `\n`. How can I tell pytest to
render the dataframe more legibly in the failure output?